# Django user authentication: django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-auth-ldap

I don't understand how to use the LDAPBackend in django, all I want to do is to authenticate a user against LDAP. I have tried the following:

```
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend
auth = LDAPBackend()
user = auth.authenticate(username='my_uid',password='pwd')
```

At this point user is None and looking at tcpdump I can't see any connection attempt to the LDAP server.

settings.py

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap.example.com'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = 'uid=%(user)s,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_AS_AUTHENTICATING_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
"first_name": "givenName",
"last_name": "sn",
"email": "mail"
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
)
```

The official django doc doesn't provide any snippet about how to use this backend in a view.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: That is true. The official django doc is extremely limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the documentation for django-auth-ldap is [here](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/). For debugging your configuration, you'll want to install a logging handler on the `'django_auth_ldap'` logger; see [Django's logging documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) for more on that.

At a glance, I would say that one problem is that `AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI` is not set to a URI; try something of the form `ldap://ldap.example.com/`. You'll also want to review the documentation for [AUTH_LDAP_BIND_AS_AUTHENTICATING_USER](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#auth-ldap-bind-as-authenticating-user): this is an advanced and somewhat subtle option that you should only enable if you know that you need it.

Comment: Hi psagers, thanks very much for your help, after prefixing the hostname with ldap:// I started to see ldap traffic, that was definitely my issue.

Comment: ref link seems down.